# Getting error while trying to save

Tags: python, shapefile, pyshp

I am getting error when I am trying to write out the file. Can somebody help me with this?

[image]

[image]

```
import shapefile 
w=shapefile.Writer(shapefile.NEW_SHAPEFILE)
w.point(2,5)
w.point(2,2)
w.point(3,5)
w.field('Id','N','6','0')
w.field('FIRST_FLD','N','19','11')
w.field('LOCATION','C','50')
w.record('12347','01','South')
w.save('shapefiles/test/new_shapefile')
```

Why does this scenario occur when I am trying to write? Can I only save under the name point/polygon/line?

Comment: Please add code and data as text, not just screenshots, so it is more easily reproducable for people trying to help

Comment: Okay. Here is the code:                                                                                        import shapefile                                                                                                    w=shapefile.Writer(shapefile.NEW_SHAPEFILE)                                                 w.point(2,3)                                                                                                              w.save('shapefiles/test/new_shapefile')                                                                I just want to know if this works.

Comment: Please add the complete code to your **question** instead, it's not very readable in comments (and there's more space)

Comment: import shapefile
w=shapefile.Writer(shapefile.NEW_SHAPEFILE)
w.point(2,5)
w.point(2,2)
w.point(3,5)
w.field('Id','N','6','0')
w.field('FIRST_FLD,'N','19','11')
w.field('LOCATION','C','50')
w.record('12347','01','South')
w.save('shapefiles/test/new_shapefile')

Comment: You may also want to look into a python IDE

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare a shapefile type when you create the writer:

```
w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)
```

Comment: I would like to know if I can save it in a new name other than point,lines and polygon. If yes, I would like to know the syntax.

Comment: ??? What? w.save("whateverYouWant")